# Concat different types of observables

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java, sqlbrite

I want to concat different observables to create an activity flow, using SQLBrite to persist informations into my android sqlite database

This flow have to follow this sequence of avtivities:

1 - Create an observable responsible to open an instance of transaction

2 - concat many observables, each one responsible to insert data into tables (one observable per table)

3.a - if every data are inserted as well (doOnCompleted method), log this and set my transaction instance as successful

3.b - if has an error, log this error (doOnError method)

4 - Close my transaction instance (doOnTeminate method)

**The problem:**

Methods like doOnError, doOnCompleted and doOnTerminate doesn't send my transaction instance as parameter. There is an way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you gain anything by making the action of opening a connection an observable.  Here's a simpler way to solve your problem.

```
SomeObject transaction=new Transaction();
Observable.concat(obs1,obs2,obs3)
          .doOnCompleted(logStuff())
          .doOnError(e->)
          .doOnTerminate(transaction.close());
```